# Unable to print the output of API response with python

Tags: python, python-requests

Iam not able to print the output of the below snippet but code runs successfully.Could anyone please help on this were I am doing things wrong?

```
import requests
import json
# import pdb

def test_login_withvalidcredentials():
    URL = 'https://***api.***.com:8443/api/users/login'
    payload = {
    "username": "****.com",
    "password": "***"}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(URL,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    output = json.loads(response.content)
    # pdb.set_trace()
    print(type(output))
    print(output)
```

Comment: There can be various reasons as to why there is not output. First of all, is the request a success? If not then nothing will be printed. Secondly, if no content has been returned by the server nothing will be printed. What does `type(output)` print?

Comment: What happens if you do `json.loads(response.text)`?

Comment: The request is success.

Comment: Please find the output:   test_login.py:18: KeyError
------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------
<class 'dict'>
{'status': 200, 'data': {'refresh_token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzYjI2ODE1Ny0wN2QzLTRlYjYtYmJiYy01O
TAzMjVmNWM0YjYiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiM2IyNjgxNTctMDdkMy00ZWI2LWJiYmMtNTkwMzI1ZjVjNGI2IiwiZW1haWwiOiJoYXJpLnByYXNhZE
Btc3lzdGVjaG5vbG9naWVzLmNvbSIsInJvbGVfaWQiOiJkaXJlY3RfYWRtaW4iLCJmaXJzdF9sb2dpbiI6ZmFsc2UsIm9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbl9

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your function

```
import requests
import json
# import pdb

def test_login_withvalidcredentials():
    URL = 'https://***api.***.com:8443/api/users/login'
    payload = {
    "username": "****.com",
    "password": "***"}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(URL,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    output = json.loads(response.content)
    # pdb.set_trace()
    print(type(output))
    print(output)

test_login_withvalidcredentials()
```

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion again the same response I am getting,but output is not printed please find the output below

Comment: pytest test_login.py
=========================================== test session starts ============================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: E:\***\API
collected 1 item                                                                                            

test_login.py .